# Register / Enqueue Scripts

Tags: jquery, javascript

I am trying to be neat and put all JS into .js files and register and enqueue them. So far I have 'great' success doing so. I have in my functions.php of my theme:

```
wp_register_script( 'myscript', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/jquery.myscripts.js', array( 'some-other-script' ), '1.0.6', true );
```

Like this the script is called after the JS script that is creating the DOM I hope to use in my JS file. And it seems to look good in my source of the website:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://example.com/wp-content/plugins/some-other-plugin/lib/some-other-plugin/some-other-script.js?ver=3.2.2"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://example.com/wp-content/themes/some-theme/js/jquery.myscript.js?ver=1.0.5"></script>
```

In my template file of the page in question I have added:

```
<?php wp_enqueue_script( 'myscript' ); ?>
```

Here is my JS code, it still prints "Detected small enough window", but does not execute any code afterwards.

```
var bMenuVisible = true;

jQuery(function ($) {   
    $( document ).ready(function() {
    if( $( window ).width() < 850 ){

        console.log( "Detected small enough window" );

        $( ".someClass" ).click(function() {

            console.log( "Clickedy Click" );

            if (bMenuVisible == true) {
                $( ".some-other-class" ).fadeOut( "slow", function() {
                    console.log( "fading out!" );
                });

                bMenuVisible = false;
            }
            else {
                $( ".some-other-class" ).fadeIn( "slow", function() {                       
                    console.log( "fading in!" );
                }); 

                bMenuVisible = true;    
            }
        });
    }
```

Now to the WP related question, when I added the code to the template of the page itself it worked like a charm, but as soon as I registered it as a script and enqueued it at the very same spot, it stopped working / maybe stoped seeing the DOM. So I can't help but wonder if I am doing something wrong during the register and enqueue?

---

I have changed the JS to look the following way, no anno functions and some nicer seperation, still not working though :(

```
var bMenuVisible = true;

function myApp () {
jQuery('.royalSlider').royalSlider('updateSliderSize', true);
console.log( "ready!" );
console.log( "Window width: " + jQuery( window ).width());

if( jQuery( window ).width() < 850 ){

    console.log( "Detected small enough window" );

    jQuery( ".someClass" ).click(function() {

        console.log( "Clickedy Click" );
        console.log( jQuery( document ).ready() );

        if (bMenuVisible == true) {
            jQuery( ".some-other-class" ).fadeOut( "slow", function() {
                console.log( "fading out!" );
            });

            bMenuVisible = false;
        }
        else {
            jQuery( ".some-other-class" ).fadeIn( "slow", function() {                      
                console.log( "fading in!" );
            });

            bMenuVisible = true;    
        }
    });
 }              

}

jQuery( document ).ready( myApp );
```

Comment: Sorry, but this is a plain jQuery/JavaScript problem and not WordPress related.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read this atricle: http://lostechies.com/derickbailey/2012/05/22/function%E2%80%A6-vs-function%E2%80%A6-or-domready-vs-the-module-pattern/

Problem is most probably with:

```
jQuery(function ($) {   
    $( document ).ready(function() {
```

I don't see the point in invoking anonymous function that awaits for DOM to be ready.

Comment: If I understood correclty I would only need to remove `jQuery(function ($) {` and its closing `}` and it should work, it isn't the prefered way of the website you linked, but there shouldn't be anything wrong with that.

Comment: Well it either was what you said or a mix of that and my changes, but it works now.